# Conduction Theory

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, conductors, metals, phonons

> Why the conductivity of Metal increase with a decrease in temperature, semiconductor increase with an increase in temperature and alloys remains the same ?

**Is it due to the following reasons?**

***Metals***: Due to the formation of more free electrons
***Semiconductors***: Due to the formation of Cooper pairs and hence the creation of Phonon field
***Alloys***: No Free electrons or Phonon field created.

I found it on the Internet, Good topic to be discussed here...

Comment: You are wrong on everything or almost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metals: You don't have formation of more free electrons, there is decrease of resistivity as temperature falls. You can express conductivity as inverse of resistivity so you have $\sigma= 1/ \rho = \frac{1}{\rho_0 (1+\alpha(T - T_0))}$. As you can see conductivity depends on temperature as $\frac{1}{T}$.

For semiconductors: Formation of Cooper pairs requires very low temperatures, so it does not relate to answer to your question. Conductivity in semiconductors equals $\sigma = ne\mu_e + pe\mu_h $ where $ne$ is electron density, $\mu_e$ electron mobility, $pe$ hole density and $\mu_h$ hole mobility. Now, conductivity is proportional to charge carrier density and those densities are proportional to temperature so with rise of temperature you get more charge carriers therefore greater conductivity.

To get more info i recommend you the book "Principles of Electronic Materials and Devices" by Kasap, it is well written introduction to material science.

I don't have experience with alloys, someone else will answer that hopefully.

Edit: Clarification why charge density rises as temperature rises

As temperature rises more electrons have enough energy to get excited frome valence band to conduction band. As electron goes to conduction band hole is formed in valence band so total charge density is increased, since both electrons and holes contribute to current density.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my I think you made some mess of most of the concepts and terms...

In metals there are a lot of free electrons already. Increasing temperature **increases** the number of free (unbound) electrons, but it also increases lattice vibrations (phonons) which make the electrons scatter, and this effect is much stronger. Therefore, increasing the temperature makes it harder for the free electrons to transport the charge across the metal, as they meet more "obstacles" in their way (in terms of phonons).

In semiconductors, there is a small energy gap and at low temperatures there are very few free electrons. Increasing the temperature increases the number of free electrons significantly, and this allows the system to conduct electricity. Another way to bridge the energy gap is by increasing the voltage.

Cooper pairs do not exist in metals or semiconductors. They exist in **superconductors**.

I am no expert on alloys and not familiar enough with their conductivity properties.